# Make PasswordChar Show Characters

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a textbox that has a PasswordChar. The problem is that i want to nullify the passwordchar and let the textbox show the charcters when the users clicks a button

Pls how will i do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To reset the `PasswordChar` to show characters you use `\0`

Comment: Tried that but i can accept an answer in 8 minutes